# Mysql -u root not working, can't change password, reinstalling doesn't work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

So, all of a sudden, for no reason I could find, mysql simply stopped working in my computer. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and I've tried to reinstall mysql about 4 times, all to no avail. Whenever I try to do anything, it gives me

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

And trying [this method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) gets me as far as step 2:

"Start the mysqld demon process using the --skip-grant-tables option with this command -  `sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`" , which seems to work until I try the next step and get

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

I searched this error online, and they told me to change some config files to include --skip-grant-tables, which I did and it didn't work, either.

What else can I do? I've been trying to fix this for around three hours to no avail, and I can tell you with 100% certainty that when I left work yesterday it was working just fine. Please, is there anything I can do short of wiping the entire damn disk and starting everything over?

Comment: You are going to need to use the user who does have access.  We really can't determine which user that is because it's your MySQL configuration.

Comment: How can I find out which users have access? Or rather, whether any users exist at all? Is there a way to wipe it clean and get a new installation of mysql with default users and configuration?

Comment: In any event you need to use the MySQL user which has permissions not the Linux user.

Comment: WHat? What mysql user? I don't get it. Is it a user named 'mysql'?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html